# kafka authentication and authorization

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I read Kafka's documents

But I did not understand. Can I use username and password for Python Producers?

Can specify that any Producer can only produce a Topic, like `MySQL` .(producer has written with Python)

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can have user/pass per topic. see [official documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security) **Authorization and ACLs**.

You can enable security with either SSL or SASL, Kafka's SASL support:

- SASL/GSSAPI (Kerberos) - starting at version 0.9.0.0
- SASL/PLAIN - starting at version 0.10.0.0
- SASL/SCRAM-SHA-256 and SASL/SCRAM-SHA-512 - starting at version 0.10.2.0

From the docs, example of adding Acls:

Suppose you want to add an acl "Principals User:Bob and User:Alice are allowed to perform Operation Read and Write on Topic Test-Topic from IP 198.51.100.0 and IP 198.51.100.1". You can do that by executing the CLI with following options:
1

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --allow-principal User:Alice --allow-host 198.51.100.0 --allow-host 198.51.100.1 --operation Read --operation Write --topic Test-topic
```

Also in this [Blog post](https://medium.com/@stephane.maarek/introduction-to-apache-kafka-security-c8951d410adf) you can find some information

I'm not sure what library you are using but it should just be a matter of passing the proper properties to the producer/client; **kafka-python** has support:

- [Support SASL/Kerberos](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/533)
- [Support for ACL based kafka](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/660)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use username+password for authentication, you need to enable SASL authentication using the Plain mechanism on your cluster. See the [Authentication using SASL](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl) section on the Kafka website for the full instructions.

Note that you also probably want to enable SSL (SASL_SSL), as otherwise, SASL Plain would transmit credentials in plaintext.

Several Python clients support SASL Plain, for example:

- kafka-python: https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python
- confluent-kafka-python: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python

---

Regarding authorizations, using the default authorizer, `kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer`, you can restrict a producer to only be able to produce to a topic. Again this is all fully documented on Kafka's website in the [Authorization and ACLs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz) section.

For example with SASL Plain, by default, the Principal name is the username that was used to connect. Using the following command you can restrict user `Alice` to only be able to produce to the topic named `testtopic`:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Alice --producer --topic testtopic
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this :

```py
    topic = "test"
    sasl_mechanism = "PLAIN"
    username = "admin"
    password = "pwd$"
    security_protocol = "SASL_PLAINTEXT"

    #context = ssl.create_default_context()
    #context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
    #context.options &= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, bootstrap_servers='kafka1:9092',
                              #api_version=(0, 10),
                              security_protocol=security_protocol,
                              #ssl_context=context,
                              #ssl_check_hostname=True,
                              #ssl_cafile='../keys/CARoot.pem',
                              sasl_mechanism = sasl_mechanism,
                              sasl_plain_username = username,
                              sasl_plain_password = password)
                              #ssl_certfile='../keys/certificate.pem',
                              #ssl_keyfile='../keys/key.pem')#,api_version = (0, 10))
```